# Removing Wordpress code from footer that uses do_action

Tags: wordpress

I am reading documentation on how to remove sections/content of a parent theme that uses do_action('action_name') from my child theme. As much as I think I understand it, it is still not working. All I am trying to do at the moment is remove the footer parent theme copyright section in my child theme. I have the action name and the parent function that calls it. I can add content to the footer but I can not remove what is currently there.

I have looked through my theme parent theme files and construction_base_footer_copyright is indeed what calls the footer info I am trying to remove. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help you can give.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

** Parent Theme Footer.php **

```
<?php
  /**
   * Hook - construction_base_action_footer.
   *
   * @hooked construction_base_footer_copyright - 10
   */
  do_action( 'construction_base_action_footer' );
?>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Child Theme Functions.php**

```
add_action('construction_base_action_footer', 'action_name');

function action_name() {
  remove_action( 'construction_base_action_footer', 'construction_base_footer_copyright', 10 );
  echo "<p>Additional text</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that, because your hook and the parent's hook have the same priority (10), your `remove_action` is not happening fast enough, before the parent's hook triggers. You have a couple options here to fix this.

---

A) Up the priority of your own function so that `remove_action` happens before the copyright triggers. Change:

```php
add_action('construction_base_action_footer', 'action_name');
```

to:

```php
add_action('construction_base_action_footer', 'action_name', 1);
```

That should be enough to fix it, but is not really a "best practices" approach.

---

B) You could just change the call to the action in `footer.php`. Copy the file to your child theme directory, and remove the `do_action('construction_base_action_footer');` line entirely and replace it with whatever content you want, or change it to call your own custom action function with a different action name. Either of these is a much better approach than option A.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for your help